# Global hotkey pressed twice, like in dictation feature

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In Mac OS ML one can setup to switch dictation on by pressing `fn` key twice. I would like to use the same global shortcut in my application. Does anyone have experience with watching for double pressed keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NSEvent you can setup a global monitor using `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` Here is the bit of code that will allow you to monitor for the `fn` key but you can of course change it no anything if you also filter for NSKeyDownMask.

```
__block double prevTimeInterval = 0;
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSFlagsChangedMask handler:^(NSEvent *theEvent) {
    if (theEvent.keyCode == 63) {
        if (theEvent.timestamp - prevTimeInterval < 0.2)
            NSLog(@"Double pressed fn key");
        prevTimeInterval = theEvent.timestamp;
    }
}];
```

Comment: Looks nice, i will check it. Thanks.